# SignalR Failure to invoke method in server

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi, signalr-hub

I am building a xamarin app, with a .net core api.

I am trying to send and receive messages via signalR for real time chat. First time using it.

Whenever I try to invoke the SendMessage() I get:

```
failed to invoke  SendMessage()  due to an error on the server
```

here is my method in my xamarin client:

```
public partial class MessageForm : ContentPage
{
    private HubConnection hubConnection;

    public Command SendMessageCommand { get; }
    public Command ConnectCommand { get; }
    public Command DisconnectCommand { get; }

    public MessageForm(string name, object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = name;
        MessageEntry.Completed += StartMessage;
        SendMessageCommand = new Command(async () => { await SendMessage(sender, e); });
        ConnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Connect());
        DisconnectCommand = new Command(async () => await Disconnect());

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl($"http://myAPIip/chatHub")
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", message =>
        {
            //update UI 
        });


    }


    async Task Connect()
    {
        await hubConnection.StartAsync();

    }


    async Task Disconnect()
    {
        await hubConnection.StopAsync();

    }


    async Task SendMessage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        await Connect(); 

        var model = new MessageViewModel
        {
            MessageContent = MessageEntry.Text,
            Receiver = Title,
            Sender = await SecureStorage.GetAsync("currentUser")
        };

        await hubConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage", model);
    }

    async void StartMessage(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await SendMessage(sender, e); 
    }

}
```

}

I've looked on existing posts and the most common cause of this are incorrect method names in the client that dont match up to the server

however I dont see any issue with any of that in my code, they all seem to match up, here is my server side chathub code:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }

}
```

unless im being extremely dense, it all looks correct!

It doesnt even seem to hit this part of the code, I get the above error once the attempt is made.

Any ideas? I'm obviously missing something!

Comment: the client is sending a MessageViewModel and the server is expecting a string

Comment: goddamn it! thats absolutely the case! thanks so much, I think the lack of sleep has defo gotten to me!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @jason for pointing out that the client is sending a MessageViewModel and the server is expecting a string

changed my code to:

```
    public async Task SendMessage(Message message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
    }
```

and now i should go to bed before I embarrass myself anymore :D

Comment: Thanks for your sharing, please do not forget to accept your answer after two days, it will help others who have similar issue.